# setting a default month & year before filtering a pie chart using FusionCharts

Tags: javascript

I am working on creating a pie chart with month filter. I have already built it including the filter. when I select a month & year, it filters the data. But I want to set a default value as month(current month) & year(current year). How do I set the default values??

```js
var json = [
    {
        "Date": "1999-11-03",
        "label": "Tatiana Skinner",
        "value": 99,
        "color": "#f8bd19"
    },
    {
        "Date": "2022-12-18",
        "label": "Kato Burke",
        "value": 49,
        "color": "#f8bd19"
    },
    {
        "Date": "2022-12-18",
        "label": "Len Foley",
        "value": 41,
        "color": "#f8bd19"
    }
];
var json2 =[
    {
        "Date": "2022-12-18",
        "label": "Alvin Woodard",
        "value": 38,
        "color": "#33ccff"
    },
    {
        "Date": "1999-11-03",
        "label": "Hop Briggs",
        "value": 58,
        "color": "#33ccff"
    }
];
var json3 = [
    {
        "Date": "2022-12-18",
        "label": "Katell Norton",
        "value": 92,
        "color": "#ffcccc"
    },
    {
        "Date": "2022-10-11",
        "label": "Quinn Parks",
        "value": 64,
        "color": "#ffcccc"
    }
];


// Get a reference to the <input type="month"> element
const monthInput = document.querySelector('input[type="month"]');

// Add an onChange event listener to the input element
monthInput.addEventListener('change', event => {
  // Get the value of the input element
  const dateString = event.target.value;


  // Parse the date string using the Date object
  const date = new Date(dateString);

  // Extract the year and month values from the Date object
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1; // add 1 to the month value, since it is zero-indexed



  const data = json.filter(obj => {
    // Use a regular expression to check if the Date property
    // matches the yyyy-mm-dd format
    const dateFormat = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;
    if (!dateFormat.test(obj.Date)) {
      return false;
    }

    // Split the date string into its component parts
    const dateParts = obj.Date.split('-');
    const dateYear = parseInt(dateParts[0], 10);
    const dateMonth = parseInt(dateParts[1], 10);

    // Check if the date year and month match the filter values
    return dateYear === year && dateMonth === month;
  });
  const data2 = json2.filter(obj => {
    // Use a regular expression to check if the Date property
    // matches the yyyy-mm-dd format
    const dateFormat = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;
    if (!dateFormat.test(obj.Date)) {
      return false;
    }

    // Split the date string into its component parts
    const dateParts = obj.Date.split('-');
    const dateYear = parseInt(dateParts[0], 10);
    const dateMonth = parseInt(dateParts[1], 10);

    // Check if the date year and month match the filter values
    return dateYear === year && dateMonth === month;
  });
  const data3 = json3.filter(obj => {
    // Use a regular expression to check if the Date property
    // matches the yyyy-mm-dd format
    const dateFormat = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;
    if (!dateFormat.test(obj.Date)) {
      return false;
    }

    // Split the date string into its component parts
    const dateParts = obj.Date.split('-');
    const dateYear = parseInt(dateParts[0], 10);
    const dateMonth = parseInt(dateParts[1], 10);

    // Check if the date year and month match the filter values
    return dateYear === year && dateMonth === month;
  });
  // console.log(data);


  const Incomesum = data.reduce((acc, o) => acc + parseInt(o.value), 0)
  const Expensesum = data2.reduce((acc, o) => acc + parseInt(o.value), 0)
  const Costsum = data3.reduce((acc, o) => acc + parseInt(o.value), 0)
  FusionCharts.ready(function() {
    var topProductsChart = new FusionCharts({
      type: 'multilevelpie',
      renderAt: 'chart-container',
      id: "myChart",
      width: '500',
      height: '500',
      dataFormat: 'json',
      dataSource: {
        "chart": {
          "caption": "Accounts",
          "subcaption": "Last Quarter",
          "showPlotBorder": "1",
          "piefillalpha": "60",
          "pieborderthickness": "2",
          "piebordercolor": "#FFFFFF",
          "hoverfillcolor": "#CCCCCC",
          "numberprefix": "tk",
          "plottooltext": "$label, $valuetk, $percentValue",
          "theme": "fusion"
        },
        "category": [{
          "label": "Account Types",
          "color": "#ffffff",
          // "value": "150",
          "category": [{
            "label": "Income",
            "color": "#f8bd19",
            "value": Incomesum,
            "tooltext": "Income, $valuetk, $percentValue",
            "category": data
          }, {
            "label": "Expenses",
            "color": "#33ccff",
            "value": Expensesum,
            "tooltext": "Expenses, $valuetk, $percentValue",
            "category": data2
          }, {
            "label": "Cost of good sold",
            "color": "#ffcccc",
            "value": Costsum,
            "tooltext": "$valuetk",
            "category": [{
              label: Costsum.toFixed(2),
              value: Costsum,
              color: '#ffcccc'
            }]
          }]
        }]
      }
    });
    topProductsChart.render();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="month">Enter the month:</label><br>
  <input type="month"><br>
</form>
<div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will render here</div>
```

In the above snippet, the pie chart will be loaded when you select a month and year. But I want a default value set so the Pie chart will already be loaded when the page is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little restructuring you can achieve that. Just move the rendering code to a new function `renderChart` in the below example. Then you create a load event like this

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const date = new Date();
  renderChart(date)
});
```

which calls the new function and renders with todays date.

```js
var json = [{
    "Date": "1999-11-03",
    "label": "Tatiana Skinner",
    "value": 99,
    "color": "#f8bd19"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2022-12-18",
    "label": "Kato Burke",
    "value": 49,
    "color": "#f8bd19"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2022-12-18",
    "label": "Len Foley",
    "value": 41,
    "color": "#f8bd19"
  }
];
var json2 = [{
    "Date": "2022-12-18",
    "label": "Alvin Woodard",
    "value": 38,
    "color": "#33ccff"
  },
  {
    "Date": "1999-11-03",
    "label": "Hop Briggs",
    "value": 58,
    "color": "#33ccff"
  }
];
var json3 = [{
    "Date": "2022-12-18",
    "label": "Katell Norton",
    "value": 92,
    "color": "#ffcccc"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2022-10-11",
    "label": "Quinn Parks",
    "value": 64,
    "color": "#ffcccc"
  }
];


// Get a reference to the <input type="month"> element
const monthInput = document.querySelector('input[type="month"]');

// Add an onChange event listener to the input element
monthInput.addEventListener('change', event => {
  renderChart(event.target.value)
})

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const date = new Date();
  renderChart(date)
});

function renderChart(dateString) {
  // Get the value of the input element
  //const dateString = event.target.value;


  // Parse the date string using the Date object
  const date = new Date(dateString);

  // Extract the year and month values from the Date object
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1; // add 1 to the month value, since it is zero-indexed



  const data = json.filter(obj => {
    // Use a regular expression to check if the Date property
    // matches the yyyy-mm-dd format
    const dateFormat = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;
    if (!dateFormat.test(obj.Date)) {
      return false;
    }

    // Split the date string into its component parts
    const dateParts = obj.Date.split('-');
    const dateYear = parseInt(dateParts[0], 10);
    const dateMonth = parseInt(dateParts[1], 10);

    // Check if the date year and month match the filter values
    return dateYear === year && dateMonth === month;
  });
  const data2 = json2.filter(obj => {
    // Use a regular expression to check if the Date property
    // matches the yyyy-mm-dd format
    const dateFormat = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;
    if (!dateFormat.test(obj.Date)) {
      return false;
    }

    // Split the date string into its component parts
    const dateParts = obj.Date.split('-');
    const dateYear = parseInt(dateParts[0], 10);
    const dateMonth = parseInt(dateParts[1], 10);

    // Check if the date year and month match the filter values
    return dateYear === year && dateMonth === month;
  });
  const data3 = json3.filter(obj => {
    // Use a regular expression to check if the Date property
    // matches the yyyy-mm-dd format
    const dateFormat = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;
    if (!dateFormat.test(obj.Date)) {
      return false;
    }

    // Split the date string into its component parts
    const dateParts = obj.Date.split('-');
    const dateYear = parseInt(dateParts[0], 10);
    const dateMonth = parseInt(dateParts[1], 10);

    // Check if the date year and month match the filter values
    return dateYear === year && dateMonth === month;
  });
  // console.log(data);


  const Incomesum = data.reduce((acc, o) => acc + parseInt(o.value), 0)
  const Expensesum = data2.reduce((acc, o) => acc + parseInt(o.value), 0)
  const Costsum = data3.reduce((acc, o) => acc + parseInt(o.value), 0)
  FusionCharts.ready(function() {
    var topProductsChart = new FusionCharts({
      type: 'multilevelpie',
      renderAt: 'chart-container',
      id: "myChart",
      width: '500',
      height: '500',
      dataFormat: 'json',
      dataSource: {
        "chart": {
          "caption": "Accounts",
          "subcaption": "Last Quarter",
          "showPlotBorder": "1",
          "piefillalpha": "60",
          "pieborderthickness": "2",
          "piebordercolor": "#FFFFFF",
          "hoverfillcolor": "#CCCCCC",
          "numberprefix": "tk",
          "plottooltext": "$label, $valuetk, $percentValue",
          "theme": "fusion"
        },
        "category": [{
          "label": "Account Types",
          "color": "#ffffff",
          // "value": "150",
          "category": [{
            "label": "Income",
            "color": "#f8bd19",
            "value": Incomesum,
            "tooltext": "Income, $valuetk, $percentValue",
            "category": data
          }, {
            "label": "Expenses",
            "color": "#33ccff",
            "value": Expensesum,
            "tooltext": "Expenses, $valuetk, $percentValue",
            "category": data2
          }, {
            "label": "Cost of good sold",
            "color": "#ffcccc",
            "value": Costsum,
            "tooltext": "$valuetk",
            "category": [{
              label: Costsum.toFixed(2),
              value: Costsum,
              color: '#ffcccc'
            }]
          }]
        }]
      }
    });
    topProductsChart.render();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="month">Enter the month:</label><br>
  <input type="month"><br>
</form>
<div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will render here</div>
```

Comment: Thank You. This works fine. One more problem. When I select October 2022, It shows the Income & Expense(overlaps). Is there any way that I can put a condition on the array so that only the existed data will be shown??